# How to create TCP client in C# that can recover from server disconnect

Tags: c#-4.0, tcpclient

I am building a TCP client application in C#.  It connects to a server.  Under normal conditions the server sends out new data every second.  My client application parses the byte stream, saves it to the database and then waits for the next message from the server. It runs on a separate thread and should continue receiving messages and processing them as long as the main application is running.  However there may be times where the server goes away or the network connection is temporarily lost, etc.  My code needs to be able to recover from that and continue processing server messages if the server comes back online or is again reachable.  My current code seems to hang when the server is disconnected and the only way to get it to process again is to shut it down completely and then restart it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
bool IsCancelled = false;
IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(myIPAddress), myPort);
TCPClient _tcpClient = new TCPClient();
_tcpClient.Connect(_ipEndPoint);
NetworkStream _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();

while(!IsCancelled)
{
  _data = new byte[10025];
  if(_networkStream.CanRead)
  {
    _bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(_data, 0, (int)_tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
    if(_bytesRead > 0)
    {
      ...Process data...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how steady are the 1-second pulses? could you assume that if 3 seconds passes between responses that the connection is dead and reconnect?

Comment: Sure - I could wait 3 seconds or 5 seconds or whatever.  I guess I am not even 100% sure where it is hanging and why.  At some point in my WHILE loop the server goes away.  I was assuming originally that _networkStream.CanRead would be false.  I figured eventually it would come back as true and the processing code would continue.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: stream processing is asynchronous by nature, so unless you write some non-blocking implementation, the stream will wait for the next bit of the stream. by using a (thead-safe) timer, you could abort your connection and reconnect.

Comment: client is connecting to server outside loop. if you need recover it , you need move that code inside,add additional code to reconnect to server if fail.